# Keep Facebook login when opening UIWebView

Tags: uiwebview, uikit, ios6, facebook-ios-sdk

I've integrated new facebook ios sdk to my app, implemented authentication to facebok within my app, and implemente post to wall. I'm using internal facebook credentials stored in settings in iOS 6.

Now I need to open a UIWebView on a specific facebook page (http://facebook.com/what-so-ever). But when my UIWebView is loaded it seems that the user needs to login to his facebook account again. Is there a way to keep facebook authentication within my app in UIWebView?

Comment: Why is it you need to display it through a UIWebview? Why can you just open the Facebook app, as it is intended?

Comment: I assure you there are reasons. The main one is that the client wants it this way.

Comment: The simple answer is "no". The long answer is that you could prepopulate the credentials in the fields on the web site using a number of hacky techniques, but that's a bad idea because it's likely to break whenever Facebook changes their site.